# Saving as scraped output

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

From rss feeds, i was able to scrape the content from each feed but now attempting to save each output into individual txt files with their titles e.g newstitle1.txt, newstitle2.txt...but so far, using the code below, it saves only the last output from the list. any ideas on how to fix this?

```
with open('textfile.txt', 'w') as handle:
        handle.write(text)
    counter+=1
```

Comment: use `open('textfile.txt', 'a')`

Comment: that appends the output. I want a txt file for each output instead

Comment: I don't see any change to the file name `textfile.txt`, it'll get overwritten every time.

Comment: Use individual file name for individual data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# somewhere in code

counter = 0

# in place where you save it

with open('textfile' + str(counter) + '.txt', 'w') as handle:
    handle.write(text)
counter+=1
```

or if you have title in variable `newstitle`

```
with open(newstitle + '.txt', 'w') as handle:
    handle.write(text)
```

and look out on native letters, space and other strange chars in filename.